# JAXB How to ignore node that causes exception while unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How to ignore node that causes exception due to invalid value.
Suppose I put string value instead of int in xml attribute as shown in below xml

```
<customer id="1002re">
    <name>NameTestContact</name>
    <contact>902323232</contact>
</customer>
```

Program will be terminated with exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Not a
>   number: 1002re

Is there any way in **Jaxb** to ignore invalid values or simply skip that node and keep continuing parsing other xml nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this with an [`XmlAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html). For an introduction, see [this](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html) blog post by the MOXy lead developer Blaise Doughan.

So you'd have the adapter implementation something like this:

```
public final class NumberFormatIgnoringAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Integer> {
   @Override
   public String marshal(Integer arg0) throws Exception {
      return arg0.toString();
   }

   @Override
   public Integer unmarshal(String arg0) throws Exception {
      try {
         return Integer.parseInt(arg0);
      }
      catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         return -1; // or whatever you'd like to set invalid input to
      }
   }
}
```

and add the adapter annotation to the `id` field:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(NumberFormatIgnoringAdapter.class)
private Integer id;
```